# Pulling a dynamic day range from the previous year in DB2

Tags: sql, date, db2, ibm-midrange

I have two current SQL queries that I currently use to compare GM% from previous year vs. GM% this year.  This is a daily report that I run every morning.  The date arithmetic is not very solid and I am trying to find an alternative. Previously I thought that the report would only be for Monday forward, and not including the current day (ie if ran on Tuesday, it would only pull Monday.  If ran on Monday it would not pull anything.)  Recently that has changed to where when the report is ran on Monday, they want to see Friday-Sunday.  What I am considering is setting it to pull the previous 5 day, not including the current day. (Ran on Monday would pull Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun.)  The problem is that it has to be a day this year vs same day last year comparison.  Anyone who;s tried this knows that it is not easy to get this.  Here is my current code for the date arithmetic.  I am at a loss guys, I could use some help.

```
Where DB1.TB1.CLM1>=Current Date-364 days - (DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT DATE) - 2) DAYS 
      And DB1.TB1.CLM1< Current Date- 364 days
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I hear you right, on Tuesday you would pull stats for Monday.  Wed, you pull stats for Mon-Tues.  Friday, you pull Mon-Thurs.  And for all of these, you need the equivalent day prior year.

The trick is that now on Monday, you need to pull the previous weekend, i.e. Thu-Sun.

You have not defined what to do on Sunday, so I'm leaving that case out.

Try this WHERE statement:

```
where
   ( -- do this after Monday
   dayofweek(current date) > 2 and
   DB1.TB1.CLM1 between ((current date - 364 days) - (dayofweek(current date) - 2) days) and (current_date - 365 days)
   ) 
   or
   ( -- do this on Monday
   dayofweek(current date) = 2 and
   DB1.TB1.CLM1 between (current date - 368 days) and (current date - 365 days)
   )
```

Comment: Looking at this will the where statement resolve depending on the day I run it.  So if I run on Monday it will pull everything previously, if I run it on it will only pull Monday?  That is what was stumping me is the jump across weeks from one year to the next.

Comment: Also just to clarify when I first looked at it I assumed I would have two separate SQL's that would pull this data down.

Comment: You do not need 2 separate SQL statements -- a WHERE clause like this will check the day for you

Comment: There is of course the issue of 'what is a year ago?'  If one year is a leap year and the other isn't, what is one year ago? select week(current date), week(current date - 365 days), dayofweek(current date), dayofweek(current date - 365 days), dayofyear(current date), dayofyear(current date - 365 days) from sysibm.sysdummy1;  Do you need 2013 week 8 Monday vs 2012 week 8 Monday or 2013 day 53 vs 2012 day 54?

Comment: 364 days is generally the equivalent day (same day of week) prior year, and it works for leap years.  OP said he is comparing business metrics year-over-year, in most cases, same weekday is preferred.  Yes, sometimes you get exceptions -- compare July 4th this year to last year -- or right around Dec 31 when -364 days may not be a previous year.  But this framework will work for the OP 99% of the time and he can follow the pattern to create unique use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function YEAR to extract only that part if that's the only things that it is dynamic.

```
BETWEEN YEAR(current date)-1 || '-01-01' AND YEAR(current date)+1 || '-12-31'
```